# Best practice: save in controller or create:request

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, entity-relationship

Im building an API on Laravel 4 (product information management).
Got products with translations with Eloquent relationship between them. A product hasMany translation.

When I am calling a store on API, I am storing a new product but also a new translation (a product without default translation is not useful)
To achieve that two ways:

```
$product = new Product(Input::all()))->save();
$product->translations()->save(Input::all());
```

Works great, got a new product with default translation.

Another way to think it:

```
$product = new Product(Input::all()))->save();
$request = Request::create(
'/product/'.$product->id ./translations, 'POST',Input::all());
```

Second question:

If translation failed to be stored, product is stored in DB (first save request), is it possible to avoid this, store only product if translation ok in DB?

Which one is the best practice?

Comment: No one on this ? regards

Answer (score 0):

You should look into using transactions in the [Laravel documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/database#database-transactions).

Also, you're using `Input::all()` blindly which isn't a good idea. You should specify only the input you need using `Input::only(['one', 'two', 'three'])`

Comment: Great !! transactions are what i need :-), so my first question is no longer useful, i have to implement save method of laravel not API request ?